Compare both the columns from Text values
I have a data set having IN & OUT columns with text string.
Compared text "Yes", "NA", "N/A", "No", "Partial".
If it is matching both the columns then 0 else 1.
If any column having NA or N/A that also be considered as "Yes".
Some times data will receive with Comments.
Some how I managed with this formula. Any better solution rather than this.
Thank you.
=N(IF(ISERROR(IFERROR(SEARCH("Yes",E3),IFERROR(SEARCH("n/A",E3),SEARCH("NA",E3)))),IF(ISERR(SEARCH("Partial",E3)),"No","Partial"),"Yes")<>IF(ISERROR(IFERROR(SEARCH("Yes",F3),IFERROR(SEARCH("N/A",F3),SEARCH("NA",F3)))),IF(ISERR(SEARCH("Partial",F3)),"No","Partial"),"Yes"))





IN
**OUT **




Partial- needs to be considered
Yes - Worked well


Yes - worked well
Yes


Partial- needs to be considered
Partial - "applied"


NA
Yes - Worked well


N/A - Not applicable
Yes- Worked well


NA - Not applicable
N/A


NA- not applicable
NO - not applicable


No
Yes




Post data as text table so that we can copy. Your result columns output if correct with current formula or not?

@Harun24hr sir, I have pasted separately Hope this works. I am not getting how to paste here in table format.

It's unclear with given image and explanation what your logic needs to be. Focus to explaining the logic and post samples with expected outcome (as markdown table https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Also, is NO - not applicable considered NO or N/A?

@P.b Thank you sir, I've updated tabular format. only NA, N/A should be considered as Yes. Rest everything should be equal as per the text. No does not equal to NA or N/A.

This is a solution that spills the result in Office 365:
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(B3:C10,{" ","-"}),y,IF(ISNA(XMATCH(x,{"NA","N/A"})),x,"Yes"),N(TAKE(y,,1)<>DROP(y,,1)))

Where x is the Textsplit of the whole range on (first found) space character or minus sign in each string; resulting in the first word of each cell.
y matches these strings to equal N/A or NA, if so return Yes, else return the string.
Last we compare the strings of the first and last column of y

Maybe simpler workaround works for all words before the - sign.
=N(IF(OR(TRIM(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A16,"-"),,1))={"NA","N/A"}),"YES",TRIM(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A16,"-"),,1)))<>IF(OR(TRIM(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(B16,"-"),,1))={"NA","N/A"}),"YES",TRIM(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(B16,"-"),,1))))


Same but different: =LET(x,LAMBDA(y,TRIM(@TEXTSPLIT(y,"-",,1))),z,LAMBDA(y,IF(OR(x(y)={"NA","N/A"}),"Yes",x(y))),N(z(B3)<>z(C3)))
